# DDR4 3200 32G*2 system

Tags: processor, pc

At 2020.Q1 most dual channel system that support DDR4 3200 only support reduced frequency when all four DIMMs are installed. To build a dual channel PC with 64GB DDR4 3200, 2*32GB DDR4 3200 is needed. 32GB DDR4 are becoming available now.

Another problem is some DDR4 DIMMs are said by customer service to be intel-only, not recommended for AMD. I think this is wrong, since DIMMs are tested by standard, then any DDR4 3200 DIMM will work at 3200 with any CPU/Motherboard that support DDR4 3200 (both are from top vendors). So it is even more not sure whether 32GB*2 DDR4 can work with AMD CPU.

What dual channel (i.e. not 4 channel/8 DIMM flagship) CPU (AMD prefered for now since most main stream Intel CPU seems doesn't support 3200 at all)/mother board/DIMM are recommended for 64GB system whose DDR4 work at 3200 speed?

Answer (score 1):

Disambiguation: I will only touch on regular desktop memory aka unbuffered DIMM, because SO-DIMM for laptops does not have the exception I will be talking about.

There are in fact a few 32GB desktop UDIMMs with only very limited support on a few (or even only one?) Intel platforms. But you can easily recognize them: they are much taller than regular memory. Overly simplified, they worked by spoofing two DIMMs on a single stick of memory https://www.anandtech.com/show/13694/double-height-ddr4-gskill-zadak-2x32gb-ddr4-3200/8
These will not work on AMD platforms, and even most combinations of Intel motherboard+CPU will not recognize them correctly. So stay away from those, which should be easy enough since they are hard to find these days anyway.

"Regular" 32GB UDIMMs enjoy much wider support, even on some older platforms that were released before 32GB UDIMMs were a thing. A recent bios version is probably a prerequisite here https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Nachgeprueft-128-GByte-DDR4-RAM-mit-AMD-Ryzen-und-Intel-Core-i-4476677.html

On the topic of memory speed: AMDs Zen2-based Ryzen 3000 CPUs have official support for up to DDR4-3200, at least with two single-rank DIMMs. AMDs official spec for memory configurations with more DIMMs and/or ranks is hard to find.
But the truth of the matter is: the memory controller in Zen2-based Ryzen CPUs is much more mature than it was with Zen1. Reaching memory transfer speeds of 3200MT/s should be easy enough, even when populating all 4 DIMM slots with dual-rank memory modules. By the way, those 32GB UDIMMs are all dual-rank, and pretty much all 16GB UDIMMs are as well.

So in conclusion: If you buy a Zen2-based Ryzen 3000 CPU (like e.g. Ryzen 7 3700X), you can use pretty much any memory configuration to get to DDR4-3200 speeds. Using 4x16GB or 2x32GB is a matter of taste, for example when using motherboards with only 2 DIMM slots.
The sweet-spot for performance with these CPUs seems to be around DDR4-3600. Achieving that would probably be a bit easier with only 2 DIMMs instead of 4.
Motherboards also play a role here, but daisy chain vs. t-topology seems to be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Did you mean althouth product page says 4DIMM require reduced frequency, the real product can run 4 DIMM at 3200 - will this work by luck? 32GB is the choice since even the MB have 4 slot, with 32GB you can extend to 128GB in the future. What about the intel-only recommendation? And are you sure AMD 3xxx CPU will support 2*32GB DIMM at 3200 speed?

Comment: Those are a lot of questions. Probably enough for a new question entirely... As always with memory compatibility, there are no 100% answers. There is always a slim chance that something won't work, no matter how much research effort you put in. Chances of getting 2x32GB UDIMM to work at DDR4-3200 on Zen2-based Ryzen 3000 CPUs are pretty high. Please keep in mind that the Ryzen 3000 APUs are still basically Zen1, with all the memory compatibility issues that come with it.